# Can't see textures or colors on vertices being drawn

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, vertex, opentk

I have the following code in OpenTK:

```
        unsafe
        {
            Vector3* data = (Vector3*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(
                                  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Vector3)) * simpleVertices.Count);
            Vector2* uv = (Vector2*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(
                                  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Vector2)) * simpleVertices.Count);
            for(int i = 0; i < simpleVertices.Count; i++)
            {
                ((Vector3*)data)[i] = simpleVertices[i];
                Vector2 thisuv = uvData[i];
                ((Vector2*)uv)[i] = uvData[i];

            }

            GL.BindTexture(All.Texture2D, texture.GLTexture.OpenGLName);
            GL.TexParameter(All.Texture2D, All.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
            GL.TexParameter(All.Texture2D, All.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);

            byte []squareColors = new byte[simpleVertices.Count];
            Random.NextBytes(squareColors);

            GL.ColorPointer (vertices.Count, All.UnsignedByte, 0, squareColors);

            GL.VertexPointer(3, All.Float, sizeof(Vector3), new IntPtr(data));
            GL.DrawArrays(All.Triangles, 0, simpleVertices.Count);


            Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)data);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)uv);
        }
```

I know the data being given for vertices anduv are correct (at least they work fine in my XNA renderer) and what I'm seeing is white polygons being drawn correctly on screen.

From my code above I should be seeing an assortment of colours since I'm populating squareColours with a random number of bytes (I've verified that squareColors is being filled up with random bytes) but I'm not, the vertices are all being drawn as white.

I've also tried binding a texture (via GL.BindTexture) and that has also failed.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

edit: when I added to enable color (see first comment on this post) the app crashed out with the following output:

> Stacktrace:
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   OpenTK.Graphics.ES11.GL/Core.DrawArrays
>   (OpenTK.Graphics.ES11.All,int,int)    at
>   OpenTK.Graphics.ES11.GL.DrawArrays
>   (OpenTK.Graphics.ES11.All,int,int)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/OpenGLES/OpenTK/Graphics/ES11.iPhone/GL.cs:1326
>   at Jabber.J3D.Shape.Draw_IOS ()
>   [0x00171] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/Engine/J3D/Shape_iOS.cs:136
>   at Jabber.J3D.Shape.Draw () [0x00000]
>   in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/Engine/J3D/Shape.cs:255
>   at Jabber.J3D.PhysicShape.Draw ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/Engine/J3D/PhysicShape.cs:46
>   at Jabber.Scene.GameScene.Draw ()
>   [0x0001d] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/Engine/Scene/GameScene.cs:299
>   at
>   Jabber.GameScreenManager.Screen.Draw
>   () [0x0001f] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/Engine/GameScreenManager/Screen.cs:150
>   at
>   ChicksnVixens.Screens.GameplayScreen.Draw
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/Screens/GameplayScreen.cs:481
>   at
>   Jabber.GameScreenManager.ScreenManager.Draw
>   () [0x00054] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/Engine/GameScreenManager/ScreenManager.cs:92
>   at Jabber.BaseGame.Draw
>   (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime)
>   [0x0002c] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/Engine/BaseGame.cs:95
>   at
>   ChicksnVixens.ChicksnVixensGame.Draw
>   (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/ChicksnVixensGame.cs:414
>   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoDraw
>   (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime)
>   [0x0001e] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/ExEn/ExEnCommon/Game/GameCommon.cs:205
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ExEnEmTouchGameView.OnRenderFrame
>   (OpenTK.FrameEventArgs) [0x0002e] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/ExEn/ExEnEmTouch/ExEnEmTouchGameView.cs:329
>   at
>   OpenTK.Platform.iPhoneOS.iPhoneOSGameView.RunIteration
>   () [0x000af] in
>   /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/OpenGLES/OpenTK/Platform/iPhoneOS/iPhoneOSGameView.cs:592
>   at
>   MonoTouch.Foundation.NSActionDispatcher.Apply
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/shared/Foundation/NSAction.cs:45
>   at (wrapper runtime-invoke)
>   object.runtime_invoke_void_*this*_
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)    at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)    at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in
>   /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26
>   at ChicksnVixens.Program.Main
>   (string[]) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/ahmedhakeem/Documents/Projects/JabberEngine2/MyCode/ChicksnVixens/MonoTouch
>   Program.cs:24   at (wrapper
>   runtime-invoke)
>   .runtime_invoke_void_object
>   (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>
> Native stacktrace:
>
> 0   aChicks
>   0x000c5d00 mono_handle_native_sigsegv
>   + 343     1   aChicks                             0x0000fce0 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler
>   + 322     2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x95fee48b _sigtramp + 43   3   ???
>   0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295   4
>   GLEngine
>   0x08645753 gleLLVMArrayFunc + 67  5
>   GLEngine
>   0x0863cba2
>   gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore + 856
>     6   GLEngine
>   0x08642bbe glDrawArrays_IMM_Exec + 332
>     7   OpenGLES
>   0x0087c308 glDrawArrays + 57  8   ??? 
>   0x0c3c9b34 0x0 + 205298484    9   ???
>   0x0c3c9a9c 0x0 + 205298332    10  ???
>   0x0f0956c8 0x0 + 252270280    11  ???
>   0x0f0939c4 0x0 + 252262852    12  ???
>   0x0f09397c 0x0 + 252262780    13  ???
>   0x0ecdb286 0x0 + 248361606    14  ???
>   0x0c3c709a 0x0 + 205287578    15  ???
>   0x0f0927c4 0x0 + 252258244    16  ???
>   0x0c3c44cd 0x0 + 205276365    17  ???
>   0x0c3c3fed 0x0 + 205275117    18  ???
>   0x0c3c3e9a 0x0 + 205274778    19  ???
>   0x0c3c3d73 0x0 + 205274483    20  ???
>   0x0cc03166 0x0 + 213922150    21  ???
>   0x0cbfd578 0x0 + 213898616    22  ???
>   0x0cbfd130 0x0 + 213897520    23  ???
>   0x05e861e8 0x0 + 99115496     24  aChicks
>   0x0000fa9b mono_jit_runtime_invoke +
>   1332  25  aChicks
>   0x001d9f01 mono_runtime_invoke + 137
>     26  aChicks
>   0x0027e52b monotouch_trampoline + 2527
>     27  Foundation
>   0x00619749 **NSFireTimer + 125    28 
>   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x014398c3
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
>   + 19  29  CoreFoundation                      0x0143ae74 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
>     30  CoreFoundation
>   0x013972c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817  31 
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x01396840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>     32  CoreFoundation
>   0x01396761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    33
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x028bc1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  34 
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x028bc289 GSEventRun + 115   35  UIKit
>   0x008abc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>     36  ???
>   0x05e84b8b 0x0 + 99109771     37  ???
>   0x05e83fb4 0x0 + 99106740     38  ???
>   0x05e83cee 0x0 + 99106030     39  ???
>   0x05e83e46 0x0 + 99106374     40  aChicks
>   0x0000fa9b mono_jit_runtime_invoke +
>   1332  41  aChicks
>   0x001d9f01 mono_runtime_invoke + 137
>     42  aChicks
>   0x001dc560 mono_runtime_exec_main +
>   669   43  aChicks
>   0x001db96e mono_runtime_run_main + 843
>     44  aChicks
>   0x0009cdd2 mono_jit_exec + 200    45 
>   aChicks
>   0x00003362 main + 3838    46  aChicks
>   0x00002249 _start + 208   47  aChicks
>   0x00002178 start + 40
>
> Debug info from gdb:
>
> /tmp/mono-gdb-commands.ZEI8zH:1: Error
>   in sourced command file: unable to
>   debug self

Comment: Did you enable the colour array? glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

Comment: I was in the process of editing my post to mention I tried that and got an error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong arguments to ColorPointer. The first argument is the number of components per color. Use 3 for RGB-colors.

Try this:

```
byte[] squareColors = new byte[simpleVertices.Count * 3];
Random.NextBytes(squareColors);
GL.ColorPointer (3, All.UnsignedByte, 0, squareColors);
```

Comment: oh blimey, you're correct! Unfortunately adding your fixes to the code did not solve my crash problem...

Comment: Perhaps you have additional calls to DrawArray somewhere where you do not specify colors? If so you should call glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY) after the call to DrawArray in your code above. Otherwise the other call to DrawArray will also try to use color values from the local buffer that is no longer allocated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable texturing:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

(should be easy to figure out the OpenTk equivalent)